# save image to custom folder titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, swift, titanium

I have developed an app to take a photo from the phone camera. But now I need to store the image to the phone memory into a folder created by me.

I have tried this:

```
var filename = Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + "/newImageFile.jpg";
var imageFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(filename);
imageFile.write(capturedImg);
```

But it does not apear in the gallery. How can I store the image to the phone memory and how can I create a costume folder in the phone memory to store the image?

Answer (score 0):

This Will Create Photo Album and save into this album.

I came up with this singleton class to handle it:

```
import Photos

class CustomPhotoAlbum {

static let albumName = "Titanium"
static let sharedInstance = CustomPhotoAlbum()

var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!

init() {

    func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection! {

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)
        let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .Any, options: fetchOptions)

        if let firstObject: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
            return collection.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection
        }

        return nil
    }

    if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() {
        self.assetCollection = assetCollection
        return
    }

    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)
    }) { success, _ in
        if success {
            self.assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
        }
    }
}

func saveImage(image: UIImage) {

    if assetCollection == nil {
        return   // If there was an error upstream, skip the save.
    }

    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
        let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
        let assetPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
        let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection)
        albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
    }, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

}

When you first instantiate the class, the custom album will be created if it doesn't already exist. You can save an image like this:

```
CustomPhotoAlbum.sharedInstance.saveImage(image)
```

**NOTE**: The CustomPhotoAlbum class assumes the app already has permission to access the Photo Library. Dealing with the permissions is a bit outside the scope of this question/answer. **So make sure PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .Authorize before you use it. And request authorization if necessary.**

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
            {
            NSData *imageData =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];   
    if(picker.sourceType==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
      {
      //to save camera roll
            [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
           [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
                                            } completionHandler:nil];
      }

            }
```

This will save image in camera roll which is taken by you